# How to split a large JTS polygon into multiple 1 km by 1 km geometries?

Tags: java, geotools, jts

I am using Java, Geotools and JTS.

I have the envelope geometry of a large polygon's geometry.

I want to split it up into a collection of polygons that are all 1 km by 1 km wide.

Any idea for how to do this?
Thank you. Peter

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my approach is nonsense !

As the earth is not flat, you can not split a polygon into real squares with identical width/length !

If you did, the squares would overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a planar projection and the GeoTools vector `GridFeatureBuilder`.

There is example code (using India) in my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296647/speed-up-geotools-vector-grid-processing).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look there !